# What is the word when someone does something nice for you then does something bad

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word when someone does something nice for you then does something bad?

For example, someone gives you a ride home to your house. And then later on comes back to rob you. What's the word used to describe the circumstances or the series of events?

Comment: Did they give you a ride in order to *case* your house? Was the whole thing a *con?*  Or was was it just opportunistic for them?

Comment: Yeah, it would seem like there was no niceness in any of his actions.

Comment: Jim brings up a good point, the intention of the person is critical in providing the right word.

Comment: I would think genuine niceness, as the alternative is some form of manipulation or sociopathy which are straightforward

Comment: There's a short, pithy two word phrase for this -- you were ***set up***.

Answer (score 1):

This could be considered an [about-face](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/about-face)

> a reversal of attitude, behavior, or point of view

As in:

> He seemed nice when he gave me a ride home, then did an about-face and came back and robbed me.